# Declaring Dates Conversion error

Tags: sql, datetime, declare

not sure what is wrong here but can someone help me here. I'm not to familair with declaring datetime in SQL.

```
declare @START datetime2 = '2013-07-17 00:00:00.00';
declare @END datetime2 = '2013-07-17 23:59:99.99';

select a.scheduledstart as StartTime, a.scheduledend as EndTime, a.ScheduledDurationMinutes as ScheduledDuration, a.activitytypecode, a.statecode, a.statuscode, a.OwnerId, b.new_SalesrepId as SalesRepID from ActivityPointerBase as a
join SystemUserExtensionBase as b on b.SystemUserId = a.OwnerId
where a.ActivityTypeCode = '4201' and a.StateCode = '1' and a.StatusCode = '3' and b.new_SalesrepId = 'CJV00100' and (a.ScheduledStart >= @START AND a.ScheduledEnd <= @END)
```

Is throwing this error:
Msg 241, Level 16, State 1, Line 2
Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string.

Comment: I have also tried declaring datetime instead of datetime2, no avail...

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to declare an invalid time for the `@END` variable. You can't have 99 in the seconds part, so change it to:

```
declare @START datetime2 = '20130717 00:00:00.00';
declare @END datetime2 = '20130717 23:59:59.99';
```

I also removed the `-` in the date to avoid language specific formats.

Answer (score 0):

you can't do this:

```
declare @END datetime2 = '2013-07-17 23:59:99.99';
```

do this:

```
declare @END datetime2 = '2013-07-17 23:59:59.99';
                                           ^^
```

remember it is year-month-day hour:minute:seconds.fraction and minutes go from 0 to 59, not 99.

Also I prefer to use end dates like this:

```
declare @END datetime2 = '2013-08-17'; --use "less than" the next day and forget time
WHERE yourColumn <@END
```